# Renaming a file using batch running in a wrapper batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, batch-rename

I'm trying to run a simple rename command for renaming an ".html" file to ".htm" file as a batch file. Following is my command:

```
ren index.html index.htm
```

This seems to be running fine as a part of CopyFiles.bat. The problem comes when I try to run this as a part of a batch wrapper WrapAll.bat. The file is renamed but the following error is logged:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Can someone please help in understanding why am I getting this error when trying to run the CopyFiles.bat within WrapAll.bat. This is impacting the subsequent commands as I'm checking for %errorlevel% to be 0 and i get %errorlevel% as 1 from this command.

**Edit:**

**Directory Structure:**

[This is the directory structure for the files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnT4Y.jpg) CopyFiles.bat/WrapAll.bat are in Coverage\Scripts and index.html is in Coverage\Code\Coverage_2

**CopyFiles.bat:**

```
    cd %~dp0

    call :DoThis

    cd "%~dp0..\Code\Coverage_2"
    if exist "index.htm" del "index.htm" /f /s /q
    ren index.html index.htm

    cd "%~dp0..\Code"
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
     ECHO "Do Something here"
    )
    exit /b %errorlevel%

    :DoThis
    ECHO "Doing this"
    exit /b %errorlevel%
```

**WrapAll.bat:**

```
    set logPath="%~dp0ErrorLog_%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.log"

    cd %~dp0
    call "CopyFiles.bat" 2>>%logPath%
```

Comment: You fail to mention is that WrapAll.bat is in a parent directory. But if you knew that was relevant to the problem, you would've been able to find the solution as well.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the directories. Relatively new to batch scripting so I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: why don't you post the at least the relevant code of your batch files? How can anyone imagine whats going on?

Comment: @elzooilogico, I have added the portion of the code throwing the error.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks for pushing me to look into directories, turns out that is where the problem was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hours of re-running the script, I finally found the issue, its not the rename but the cd command after that causing the problem.

```
cd "%~dp0..\Code"
```

should be

```
cd "%~dp0.."
```

Comment: Perhaps add switch `/D` to the `cd` command, because otherwise it will not change the directory in case it is on a different drive...

Comment: @aschipfl, thanks. that's a great suggestion! I will add the switch